# Apache2 mod_wsgi, 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I setup, django App with Apache2,

1) Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webadmin@publisy.com
    ServerName alpha101.publisy.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/media/static/
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/media/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/mysite/media/
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

2) wsgi script (located at /usr/local/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi)

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/django')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Can anybody suggest what goes wrong?

Comment: Can you check what is written in the apache error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`)?

Comment: [Tue Apr 19 09:35:23 2011] [error] Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1218622832,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
[Tue Apr 19 09:35:24 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Apr 19 09:35:25 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/2.8 Python/2.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: this KeyError is kinda normal. Nothing else in the logs?

Comment: Can you check if permissions are set properly so apache2 (or apache user) is able to access your wsgi script?

Comment: Other log: [Tue Apr 19 05:16:17 2011] [error] [client 124.41.237.129] mod_wsgi (pid=24832): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/django/publisy/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Tue Apr 19 05:16:17 2011] [error] [client 124.41.237.129] Traceback (most recent call last):
......[Tue Apr 19 05:16:17 2011] [error] [client 124.41.237.129] TemplateSyntaxError: Caught an exception while rendering: No module named destinations

Comment: see Neo's answer below I would say. ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be a little problem. Looks like your "site' directory is `/var/www/mysite`.

Add this to your python path in django.wsgi.

```
sys.path.append('/var/www')
sys.path.append('/var/www/mysite')
```

Infact the error you posted

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught an exception while rendering: No module named destinations
```

It seems that wsgi can't find the module destinations. Add the directory path to your python path in django.wsgi and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `DEBUG=False` or your ip address is not in the `INTERNAL_IPS` any django error will give you Error 500, even a thing like `KeyError`. Usually, production server has a diffences in the inviroment, so, even if everything ran ok on localhost, you might find some problems in production.

Two ways to see what is wrong:

1. Just add your ip to `INTERNAL_IPS` (get your current ip address) or set `DEBUG` to `true`
2. Take look at apache error.log or at the email that you have setup in your settings.py (errors are emailed by default)

Also, remember, that you have to restart the server after making changes.

Good luck!